# ANDV/MRO merger options

Tags: capital-gains-tax, corporate-acquisition

In the ANDV/MRO merger, ANDV shareholders can request MRO shares, cash, or a blend of both. What are the cap gains implications? I'm thinking that exchange of ANDV to MRO shares would trigger no cap gain whereas exchange of ANDV shares for cash would represent a cap gain. Am I correct?

Answer (score 1):

If you receive stock for stock  in a  merger or acquisition, it's not a taxable transaction. It doesn't matter whether the trade was voluntary or if you voted for it. Your cost basis in the new stock is the same as your cost basis in the old one.

When the deal is for stock and cash, the cash is called “boot” and the boot  must be reported  as taxable income while decreasing  your basis in the new shares by the amount of the boot. If a gain is realized on the boot, it's a taxable capital gains and it increases the basis in the new shares.  Sometimes, this can be a bit of a calculation.

Here are  two of many sites that offer examples and explanations:

https://www.schwab.com/public/file/P-8936138/spt010960.pdf

http://investor.windstream.com/static-files/02db7639-031e-40ce-a8b0-ed3acfe4cd07